# Target both x86 and x64 in the Windows Installer (VS2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, operating-system, windows-installer, target-platform

Is there any way to create a Windows Installer using Visual Studio 2008 to target both x86 and x64 operating systems.

In the TargetPlatform property, I have just : `x86`, `x64`, `Itanium`. And I know that there is another one somewhere called `Any CPU` but I can't find it.

Also, I don't want to create two Setup.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done, but not directly with Visual Studio. The general approach is this:

- create a generic MSI which contains both 32-bit and 64-bit resources
- create [MST transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372459%28VS.85%29.aspx) (one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit) which modify the MSI based on the target platform
- use an EXE bootstrapper to dynamically detect the platform and apply the correct transform to your MSI

You can create transforms with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx). If you want a commercial solution, you can try Advanced Installer or InstallShield.

If this seems too complicated, you can simply use separate 32-bit and 64-bit packages.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, but not with the VS installer. I have a colleague who has achieved this with the InstallShield product, but let me say that it was an absolute hack, and in the end he ended up with a much better result making two distinct installers, one for each target bitness.

I also need to enlighten you:

> In the TargetPlatform property, I have just : x86, x64, Itanium. And I know that there is another one somewhere called Any CPU

The `TargetPlatform` property doesn't change the bitness of the application you are installing, you are getting it mixed up with the target platform of the assemblies themselves. The MSI is the delivery vehicle, the .Net assemblies in it are the payload. `TargetPlatform` setting on the MSI doesn't govern how the .Net assemblies are JIT compiled, instead it is used to help determine installation paths (if it is set to x86 then the default installation path should be `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%`, and the different registry hives will be targeted.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure this cannot be done.
The Any-CPU you mention is used by .Net compiler for your assemblies (.Net assemblies are by default architecture agnostic, but can be forced to be compiled as x86 or x64).
But since the windows-Installer is a native win32 exe, it cannot be generated as "Any-CPU".
So you must generate 2 identical installers one for x86 and for x64.

Comment: You are partially correct - an MSI is not an executable*, it is actually a database of sorts which is read and actioned by `msiexec.exe`. (*if an "MSI" has an `.exe` suffix it is a bootstrapper wrapping an MSI, the bootstrapper is compiled code but can run on a 64 bit system without any issues).